# How to move widgets to fill empty space?

Tags: flutter, widget

I have 2 expanded containers filled with widgets, for various reasons i need to make the right one smaller without changing it's appearance or scale, (basically i just want it to move to the right to remove that empty space)

[The two components](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rc7ee.png)

the two components are inside a ROW that is the body of a scaffold, Parent:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(192, 192, 192, 1),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 250,
            width: 3000,
            child: Row(
              children: [
                DatiCliente(),
                DatiApparato(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Riparazione(),
          Uscita(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

here the code for the left component:

```
class DatiCliente extends StatefulWidget {
  const DatiCliente({super.key});

  @override
  State<DatiCliente> createState() => _DatiClienteState();
}

class _DatiClienteState extends State<DatiCliente> {
  List<String> dropdowns = List.generate(3, (index) => "");

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: FittedBox(
        fit: BoxFit.fill,
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(
              color: Colors.black,
              width: 2,
            ),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          ),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
                maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 4,
              ),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                children: [
                          //various children
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

here the code for the right one:

```
class DatiApparato extends StatefulWidget {
  const DatiApparato({super.key});

  @override
  State<DatiApparato> createState() => _DatiApparatoState();
}

class _DatiApparatpState extends State<DatiApparato> {
  List<String> dropdowns = List.generate(3, (index) => "");

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: FittedBox(
        fit: BoxFit.fill,
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(
              color: Colors.black,
              width: 2,
            ),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          ),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
                maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 4,
              ),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                children: [
                          //various children
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

i already tried fiddling with the Flex modifier and the  maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, and instead of changing the position of the right and left components, it changes the scale and or internal size

[Fiddling with flex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6veHp.png)

[Fiddling with MediaQuery.of(context).size.width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bt1QE.png)